How can fideism's pursuit of truth through faith be considered a sound epistemology when mutually exclusive religious beliefs are accepted on faith?
A Christian believes in heaven, hell, and the resurrection of Jesus on faith. A Muslim rejects the resurrection but accepts Muhammad as the true prophet on faith. A Hindu rejects both Christianity and Islam but believes in karma and reincarnation on faith. And so on.
According to SEP, Fideism is:

“Fideism” is the name given to that school of thought – to which Tertullian himself is frequently said to have subscribed – which answers that faith is in some sense independent of, if not outright adversarial toward, reason. In contrast to the more rationalistic tradition of natural theology, with its arguments for the existence of God, fideism holds – or at any rate appears to hold (more on this caveat shortly) – that reason is unnecessary and inappropriate for the exercise and justification of religious belief. The term itself derives from fides, the Latin word for faith, and can be rendered literally as faith-ism. “Fideism” is thus to be understood not as a synonym for “religious belief,” but as denoting a particular philosophical account of faith’s appropriate jurisdiction vis-a-vis that of reason.
1. A Formal Definition
Alvin Plantinga has noted that fideism can be defined as an “exclusive or basic reliance upon faith alone, accompanied by a consequent disparagement of reason and utilized especially in the pursuit of philosophical or religious truth” (87). Correspondingly, Plantinga writes, a fideist is someone who “urges reliance on faith rather than reason, in matters philosophical and religious” and who “may go on to disparage and denigrate reason” (87). Notice, first, that what the fideist seeks, according to this account, is truth. Fideism claims that truths of a certain kind can be grasped only by foregoing rational inquiry and relying solely on faith. Insofar as fideism insists that knowledge of these truths is possible, it must be distinguished from various forms of skepticism with which it otherwise shares certain common features. Notice too that this definition is largely formal; the plausibility of fideism as a philosophical doctrine and the proper extension of the term will therefore depend on the content given to the terms “faith” and “reason.”

How can faith, or fideism, be considered a sound epistemology in the pursuit of truth if mutually exclusive beliefs can be equally "justified" through faith?

How does Alvin Plantinga define faith?

Plantinga's account of faith gives us a good clue I think as to why he would gravitate
toward a picture according to which Christian beliefs are properly basic. Following
Calvin, Plantinga defines faith (or faith of the type he wishes to discuss) as a "firm
and certain knowledge" of "the central teachings of the gospel" (pp. 244-249). This
certain knowledge is not arrived at by the workings of any of the faculties we were
created with, but is the result of the work of the Holy Spirit (p. 245), who "causes us
to believe these great truths of the gospel" (p. 245). Let "Plantinga faith" be faith as
Plantinga describes it, leaving out the part about the beliefs in question constituting
knowledge. (I want to identify "Plantinga faith" in a non-evaluative way in order to
leave as an open question the status of beliefs that are the result of "Plantinga faith.")
Plantinga faith then is a very strongly held belief in the great truths of the gospel,
produced in accordance with God's plan by the Holy Spirit in the way Plantinga
describes. How strongly held? Very strongly: It is a "firm and certain" belief (p. 244),
one finds the beliefs so caused to be "compelling" (p. 250).
Would the fortunate
recipient of Plantinga faith have properly basic beliefs? Even after reading Plantinga's
defense, I don't find this matter nearly as clear as Plantinga seems to find it, but it
does seem plausible to me to suppose so.
Quoted from: https://www.baylor.edu/content/services/document.php/40620.pdf


"How can faith, or fideism, be considered a sound epistemology in the pursuit of truth if mutually exclusive beliefs can be equally "justified" through faith?" It cannot: faith is not "rational".

According to the last passage above "Plantinga's faith is a very strong held belief in the gospel resulting from  the work of the Holy Spirit". How this is different from traditional Christian views? And from a "foundational" point of view it is simply circular: we believe in God because we believe in the gospel and we believe in the gospel because the Holy Spirit has done so". ????

This question is similar to: What kind of epistemology would justify accepting religious claims that lie beyond the reach of scientific and historical verification?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@MauroALLEGRANZA I'm not a Plantinga scholar, so I don't consider myself qualified to properly answer your second comment's questions. Regarding your third comment, none of the answers addresses fideism or faith (actually, the word faith never appears in the entire page). Instead, this question is laser focused on fideism/faith only.

The same way moral sentimentalism or intuitionism is defended by moral realists as epistemology of moral facts despite widespread cultural differences in moral standards. Our faith is imperfect and its interpretations partly corrupted and fallible, but with enough faith and piety the truth shines through, etc. Justification through faith is still subject to scrutiny and revision. Indeed, fideists often charge reason with moral deficiency with faith making up for it, "faith is against reason only in the sense that it runs into conflict with a concrete form of reason that is damaged" (Evans).

How can empiricism be considered a sound epistemology in the pursuit of truth if mutually exclusive beliefs can be equally "justified" through empirical observation? -- Fideism is just as sound as empiricism as general epistemology. In science we also can only hope that "the truth" might prevail (one theory wins out or both are seen as flawed or are completely overhauled), just like the fideist hopes that others may eventually see the light... In ethics - again the same thing. We don't come by our basic values by reasoning and we cannot at will modify them. Paradigm changes are like conversion

Put simply: "My faith is correct, their conflicting faith is mistaken."

This may be more beside the point than you realize: You assume that the center-piece of religion is the cognitive domain. Some call then ‘truth-claims’.  But see this — for the differentiation between (a) cognitive (b) volitive and (c) affective domains. Fideism is really a clunkily philosophical way of  saying that philosophy (cognitive/truth aspects) plays second fiddle to affective and volitive aspects of one's life.

Also see Brad Gregory for why all this mess starts with the Protestant break from Catholicism. Short version

So it appears that for both empiricism and faith, "he who endures to the end will be..." correct? The truth comes out eventually, and if you backed the right horse you win? I think it is better to state something, put it to the test and see if you are right or wrong then and there. Find out sooner rather than later. Isn't it said that faith which is not tested is worthless?

To discuss your question one needs Plantinga’s definition of fideism and faith.
Plantinga’s definition of fideism is stated above. Notably his sentence

"Fideism claims that truths of a certain kind can be grasped only by
foregoing rational inquiry and relying solely on faith."

Concerning Plantinga's description of faith see The Extended Aquinas/Calvin Model: :

"How does this model, with its excursion into theology, provide an
answer to an epistemological question? How can it be a model for a way
in which Christian belief has or could have justification,
rationality, warrant? The answer is simplicity itself. These beliefs
do not come to the Christian just by way of memory, perception,
reason, testimony, the sensus divinitatis, or any other of the
cognitive faculties with which we human beings were originally
created; they come instead by way of the work of the Holy Spirit, who
gets us to accept, causes us to believe, these great truths of the
gospel. These beliefs don’t come just by way of the normal operation
of our natural faculties; they are a supernatural gift. Still, the
Christian who has received this gift of faith will of course be
justified (in the basic sense of the term) in believing as he does;
there will be nothing contrary to epistemic or other duty in so
believing (indeed, once he has accepted the gift, it may not be within
his power to withhold belief)"

Plantinga does not give an explicit definition of faith. But he equates “faith = believing these great truths of the gospel”.
Hence Plantinga says:

Fideism claims that truths of a certain kind can be grasped only by
foregoing rational inquiry and relying solely on faith
The Holy Spirit, who gets us to accept, causes us to believe, these
great truths of the gospel.

Plantinga states: Certain religious truths rely solely on faith, and believing these truths is a gift of the Holy Spirit. Hence the original question reduces to:

Is the Holy Spirit a means to recognize truth?

Apparently, now we left the domain of philosophical epistemology and rational argumentation, and are completely immersed into a specific religion position.
Conclusion: These statements of Plantinga about fideism and faith do not explain how to handle contradicting positions from different religions. They do not support the view that fideism is a sound method of epistemology.

I found this: https://www.baylor.edu/content/services/document.php/40620.pdf

@user80226 I also found this document. But from which of Plantinga's paper are the references? I ask because these short quotations without context seem to me a bit strange and possibly circular.

https://campuspress.yale.edu/keithderose/are-christian-beliefs-properly-basic/

You seem to be assuming a correspondence theory of truth. It is only under this theory of truth that I see the tension you're trying to present.
However, there are other relativist theories of truth, like certain pragmatic theories of truth, or constructivist theories of truth, which would not cause the same issues.

"However, there are other theories of truth, like the pragmatic theory of truth, or constructivist theories of truth, which would not cause the same issues." - Can you explain how?
